# Install the mysql2 gem for a specific mysql client version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to use the [mysql2 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) with rails 3.1.0.rc6, but I'm having some problem with my mysql client.

I'm getting this message when trying to start my server.

> Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.1.53 but the client library is 5.5.14. (RuntimeError)

How do I compile/install mysql2 so that is can use mysql 5.5.14?

I've tried using `gem pristine mysql2` without success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here was that the [MySQL2 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) was compiled for the MySQL version installed by Apple (Development package) not by me using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Using this command when installing the gem solved the problem.

`gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.14/bin/mysql_config`

Don't forget to install mysql using:

`sudo brew install mysql`

The problem now is that we somehow need to pass the option to bundler, to do that you can use [bundler config](https://web.archive.org/web/20130219021334/http://gembundler.com:80/man/bundle-config.1.html).

`bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.14/bin/mysql_config`

Running `bundle install` in your ruby app should now work.

Comment: bundle config command didn't work for me (brew mysql didn't install so install alternative version) on lion. gem pristine mysql2 actually solved it somehow! :)

Comment: This answer worked for me, however I had to perform one extra step not mentioned in the answer. When I tried to do `brew install mysql` i got the following error `Error: mysql-5.5.19 already installed
To install this version, first 'brew unlink mysql'`, so I ran this: `brew unlink mysql` before `brew install mysql` and then the rest of the steps in the answer worked and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like unmatched version with mysql client library and mysql2 compiled gem give LoadError.

So, they explictly raise RuntimeError for that

- https://github.com/luislavena/mysql-gem/commit/a600a9c459597da0712f70f43736e24b484f8a99

So, only the way I aware is, download the source from [github](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) and compile it in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in a similar situation:

```
brew reinstall mysql
gem pristine mysql2
```